# Proper way to print address of character array

Tags: c++, arrays, character

So, I have been digging into character array's lately, and I am trying to print the address of each element of a character array.

```
char a[4] = {'i','c','e','\0'};
for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
  cout<<(void*)a[i]<<" ";
  cout<<&a[i]<<" ";
  cout<<a[i]<<endl;
 }
```

The code above gives me the following output:

```
0x69 ice i
0x63 ce c
0x65 e e
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:29:23: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
       cout<<(void*)a[i]<<" ";
                       ^
```

I am not comfortable about the output of `(void*)a[i]`. Shouldn't the character addresses be 1 byte apart. I am seeing `0x69` followed by `0x63` and then by `0x65`. Is there a reason for that. And is there a relationship between the address representation and the warning sign that it is showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to print the address of each element of a character array

`(void*)a[i]` is converting the element (the `char`) itself to `void*`, not the address of the element.

You should get the address of each element as:

```
cout<<(void*)&a[i]<<" ";
//           ^
```

Or better to use `static_cast`.

```
cout<<static_cast<void*>(&a[i])<<" ";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your print value casted to `void*`, to print address, you need

```
cout<< static_cast<void*>(&a[i])<<" ";
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you are not getting the addresses. You are casting the ASCII values of the characters to a `void*` instead. This is why the values are not correct.

What you want to do is use a `static_cast` and get the address of the element `&a[i]`:

```
cout << static_cast<void*> (&a[i]) << " ";
```